# Webpack cannot resolve module 'angular' in other libraries

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-3

I am using Webpack 3.1.0 for my application which is written in Angular 1.
Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
    entry: './frontend/expert/app/expert.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/frontend/expert/dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.css$/, 
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader'
                }) 
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'img/',
                        publicPath: 'img/'
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]'
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './frontend/expert/app/index.html' 
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            angular: './frontend/expert/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'
        }
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

My expert.js is following(from where I am picking required library):

```
require('../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
require('../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js');
require('../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js');
require('../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js');
require('../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js');
require('../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js');
require('../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
require('../bower_components/angular-fullscreen/src/angular-fullscreen.js');
require('../bower_components/angular-fontawesome/dist/angular-fontawesome.js');
require('../bower_components/trumbowyg/dist/trumbowyg.min.js');
require('../bower_components/trumbowyg-ng/dist/trumbowyg-ng.js');
require('../bower_components/medium-editor/dist/js/medium-editor.min.js');
require('../bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.min.js');
window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;
```

There are modules which cant resolve 'angular', like 'angular-fullscreen' and I am getting this error:

*Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular' in '/Users/Bhavesh/myapp/frontend/expert/bower_components/angular-fullscreen/src'*

I tried resolving this by putting alias in webpack.config.js for 'angular' but it didn't work.

My application is a multi page applicaiton with 2 different angular apps
Its structured like this:

```
-bin
-models
-routes
-server
-node_modules
-webpack.config.js
-frontend
  --expert
    --bower_components
    --app
    --expert.js
  --user
    --bower_components
    --app
```

Can anyone help me out in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [expose-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/) to solve this:

```
    {
      test: require.resolve('angular'),
      use: [
        'expose-loader?angular'
      ]
    };
```

More details and how to handle other 3rd party libraries [can be found here](https://brian.olore.net/wp/2017/06/journey-to-webpack-part-3-finish-the-vendors/).

Comment: then I get this error
*Error: Cannot find module 'angular'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Bhavesh/myapp/webpack.config.js:45:31)*

Comment: what is on line 45 of your `webpack.config.js` ?